# trouble in pushing xml into db

Tags: xml, database, oracle

I am trying to push an xml file into the db but it is continuously returning errors. i'm trying the following command:

```
java OracleXML putXML -conn "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:<dbname>" -user "<user>/<password>" -rowTag "fcst" -ignoreCase -setXSLT "surface_db.xsl" -fileName "surface.xml" " SURFACE"`
```

It returned the following error:

```
oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: 'java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
 encountered during processing ROW element 4.  All prior XML row changes were rolled back. in the XML document.
    at oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave.saveXML(OracleXMLSave.java:2543)
    at oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave.saveXML(OracleXMLSave.java:2413)
    at oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave.insertXML(OracleXMLSave.java:1376)
    at OracleXML.Put_XML(OracleXML.java:483)
    at OracleXML.ExecutePutXML(OracleXML.java:398)
    at OracleXML.main(OracleXML.java:185)
```

i changed the row specifications also but it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

This is saying that you are trying to put something incoherent in a column. Maybe you are limitating a VARCHAR to any number of characters in the db and trying to insert something bigger with the xml.